# How to highlight source in Emacs compilation-mode when compilation error occurs

Tags: emacs, compilation, compilationmode

I read the documentation about compilation-mode but I didn't find any technique to hightlight source code where a compilation error occurs.

For example change the background color of the source code that produces the compilation error (like the red underline in Eclipse or Netbeans). And also a way to read the error message somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, compilation mode will highlight the error message in the compiler output and you can use that to jump to the code. If you want your code syntax checked/highlighted you might want to look at [flymake](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake), which is supposed to be able to do exactly that.

Comment: [Flycheck](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a newer plugin that does flymake better.

Answer (score 3):

Option `next-error-highlight` controls highlighting of compilation and grep hits in the source buffers.  The possibilities for this are these:

- highlight for a given time or until the next command
- highlight until the next command or until next hit visit
- do not highlight
- show location in fringe -- which indication moves with the locus

If you use library [`simple+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/simple%2b.el), then you have another possibility: highlight until the locus moves.  This highlights, like the first two possibilities above, but the highlighting does not go away -- it just moves, like the last possibility above (fringe).

That sounds like what you want.  (It is what I use.)  For `grep`, for instance, the matching text is highlighted in the source file at the location you visit.  It stays highlighted until you visit a different hit.

The same holds for the similar option `next-error-highlight-no-select`.

In addition, for `grep` and compilation to respect the new value provided by [`simple+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/simple%2b.el), you will also need libraries [`grep+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/grep%2b.el) and
[`compile+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/compile%2b.el), respectively.